# I cant seem to get the example output, my code returns true, true, false and false. Is my ranging not missing any additional conditional statement?

Tags: java

I've the following scenario:
We have a dog that likes to bark.  We need to wake up if the dog is barking at night!

Write a method shouldWakeUp that has 2 parameters.

1st parameter should be of type boolean and be named barking it represents if our dog is currently barking.
2nd parameter represents the hour of the day and is of type int with the name hourOfDay and has a valid range of 0-23.

We have to wake up if the dog is barking before 8 or after 22 hours so in that case return true.

In all other cases return false.

If the hourOfDay parameter is less than 0 or greater than 23 return false.

Examples of input/output:

- `shouldWakeUp (true, 1)` → should return `true`
- `shouldWakeUp (false, 2)` → should return `false` since the dog is not barking.
- `shouldWakeUp (true, 8)` → should return `false`, since it's not before 8.
- `shouldWakeUp (true, -1)` → should return `false` since the `hourOfDay` parameter needs to be in a range 0-23.

and this is my code:

```
public static boolean shouldWakeUp(boolean barking, int hourOfDay) {
    if (hourOfDay < 0 || hourOfDay >= 23) {
        return false;
    }
    if (hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay >= 22) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never check `if (barking)`, so how can you do something different if the dog is barking or not?

Comment: What about `barking`? You should `return barking` instead of `return true`…

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use `boolean barking` and `hourOfDay` could be `23`:

```
public static boolean shouldWakeUp(boolean barking, int hourOfDay) {
    if (!barking)
        return false;
    if (hourOfDay < 0 || hourOfDay > 23)
        return false;
    return hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay >= 22;
}
```

**Output:**

```
System.out.println(shouldWakeUp(true, 1));      // true
System.out.println(shouldWakeUp(false, 2));     // false
System.out.println(shouldWakeUp(true, 8));      // false
System.out.println(shouldWakeUp(true, -11));    // false
```

Comment: "We have to wake up if the dog is barking before 8 or *after* 22 hours so in that case return true."
Otherwise, +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static boolean shouldWakeUp(boolean barking, int hourOfDay) {
        if (hourOfDay < 0 || hourOfDay > 23) {
            return false;

        } else if (barking && (hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay > 22)) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some insightful commentary on what this code is doing for answer completeness.

Comment: good answer but the existing one was sufficient I think

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Dog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean a=shouldWakeUp(false,2);//works fine for all values
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    public static boolean shouldWakeUp(boolean barking,int hourOfDay) {
        if((barking)&&((hourOfDay>22)||(hourOfDay<8))&&(hourOfDay>=0)&&(hourOfDay<=23)) {
                return true;
    }return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain what you change, and why you change it ? :)